# Django 1.10 - Form fields ignore attributes when rendered as hidden

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have declared form, which contains `DateInput`. `DateInput` has specified `format` attribute. This will format field's date value. At the same time, the form will expect the same format upon validation.

**My Form**:

```
class CoolForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['day', 'time_from', 'time_to', 'type'] 
        widgets = {
            'day': forms.DateInput(format=('%d--%m--%Y'))
        }
```

**Template**:

```
{{ field.as_hidden }} <!-- is rendered with wrong format: -->

<input id="id_day" name="day" type="hidden" value="2017-04-30"> 


{{ field }} <!-- is rendered with correct format: -->

<input id="id_day" name="day" type="text" value="30--04--2017">
```

**Problem**:

In template when I print form using field.as_hidden, format remains unaffected from form setting. It even ignores `attr` attribute. How can I render field as `hidden`, while keeping its specified date format?

Comment: Why do you care what the format is if it's hidden? Why not use "%Y-%m-%d" in the form class? Do you really need the hidden field at all? It won't prevent users from editing it if they want to.

Comment: Project I am working on has globally defined date formats. Form I mentioned has some ajax-related javascript, and I find cumbersome to parse date value using javascript when I dont have to if there is any Djangy workaround.

Comment: How about using `{{ field }}` and hiding it with CSS?

Comment: That would work, but I consider it very "hacky" solution. Perhaps there are better workarounds.